# Show a link if the route can be activated

Tags: angular

I have a link that I can hide if the user is not authenticated...

```
<a [routerLink]="['/anticipos']"> Subidas</a>
```

If I use this directive I can see if the link is active (in the browser)

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="`enter code here`['/anticipos']"> Subidas</a>
```

But what I need is to know if the link /solicitud/crear/ can be activated if the user is authenticated or if he is a administrator (base on role)

This how I configured the guard on app.module.ts

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:'anticipos', component:AnticipoListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},

    ])
{path:'anticipos', component:AnticipoListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response - I just ran into the same problem and found a possible solution.

I use the angular injector to get the guard and then I call it's can activate method.

```
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector) {
  }
  shouldDisplayRoute(route: Route) {
    if (!(route.path && route.path.indexOf(':') < 0))
      return false;
    if (!route.canActivate)
      return true;
    for (let guard of route.canActivate) {
      let g = this.injector.get(guard) as CanActivate;
      if (g && g.canActivate) {
        var r = new dummyRoute();
        r.routeConfig = route;
        let canActivate = g.canActivate(r, undefined);
        if (!canActivate)
          return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

}

class dummyRoute extends ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }
  routeConfig;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I used the  *ngIf directive

I checked if the token was already established, if there was a token.. I show the items.. if token is not set the item is hidden

```
<a *ngIf="_autenticacionService.token" [routerLink]="['/anticipos']"> Subidas</a>
```

This is my Authentication class

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';        


import{ IAutenticacion } from './autenticacion';

@Injectable()
export class AutenticacionService{

    private _autenticacionUrl = "http://localhost:8000/login";
    public token=0;

    constructor(private _http: Http){
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    }
    private handleError(error: Response){
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server error");
    }

    login (body: IAutenticacion): Observable<boolean> {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        //let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        //let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

        return this._http.post(this._autenticacionUrl, body) // ...using post request
                         .map(
                             (res:Response) => {
                                 let token = res.json() && res.json().token;
                                 if (token) {
                                     // set token property
                                    this.token = token;
                                    // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ usuario: body.usuario, token: token }));
                                    // return true to indicate successful login
                                    return true;
                                 }else{
                                     return false;
                                 }
                             },
                         ) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); //...errors if any
    }  

    logout(): void {
        // clear token remove user from local storage to log user out
        this.token = null;
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    }
}
```

If you want to check if user is an admin, I think you can add a new var to the Authentication class and check if that variable is true in the template